# SharePoint Rest API - Set Lookup field when [Lookup Name]Id value is already in use

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, lookup, patch

I have a SharePoint list with a number field that has an internal name of [ProjectId]. I later created a lookup column with an internal name of [Project]. I need to use a REST API to update the lookup column value. However, when I use

```
"ProjectId": 403
```

It sets the number field. I know SharePoint will append a 0 to a duplicate internal name. However, in this case it was created by the system. I can expand the Lookup column using "Project/Id" in a GET call. I just can't set it.

Does anyone know how to reference the lookup id in this case?

Here is the full code:

```
// basic patch items
$.ajax({
  url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('My List')/items(1)",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "IF-MATCH": "*",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
  },
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "__metadata": {
      "type": "SP.Data.MyListListItem"
    },
    "ProjectId": 403
  }),
  method: 'PATCH',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log("success");
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function (data) {
    console.log("error");
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

I've tried these as well:

```
"Project0Id": 403
"ProjectId0": 403
```

It just returns an error saying the column doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you confirm the internal name of lookup column, follow [find internal name](https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/How%20To/Find%20the%20internal%20name%20of%20SharePoint%20column.html). Is this single selection or multiple selection lookup column?

Comment: It's a single select Lookup column. You can see the internal field name in the URL snippet below.

FldEditEx.aspx?List=[List GUID]&Field=Project